# why this media query is not working / not loading when I put it in child theme?

Tags: css, child-theme, wp-enqueue-style, parent-theme

I am trying to create a separate style sheet for responsive behavior in a site.

my folder structure:

- magzine/style.css
- magazine-child/style.css
- magazine-child/responsive.css

`Magazine` is my theme folder.

I have following codes in my `functions.php`

```
/* Adding parent style sheet to the child theme */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array('parent-style')
    );
}

/* Adding Responsive style sheet */
function responsive_css(){
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'wpa_custom',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/responsive.css'
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'responsive_css', 999 );
```

I want to do some media query for ipad mini. so I put this code in child theme `responsive.css` :

```
/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : portrait) {
    .top-header ul { padding: 0 7px !important;}
}

wh
```

en I check my theme source code I see these two lines

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='child-style-css'  href='mysite.com/riffaz/athavan-eng/wp-content/themes/magazine-child/style.css?ver=4.2.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wpa_custom-css'  href='mysite.com/riffaz/athavan-eng/wp-content/themes/magazine-child/responsive.css?ver=4.2.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

So those style sheets are loaded into my site's head.
That's fine.

When I put something on my child theme `style.css` it takes affect. I see the edits on the front end.

BUT when I put **media queries** into child theme `style.css` or in `responsive.css` it does NOT work.

I'm barely confused why is this..

BUT if put the CSS code in an existing media query into my **PARENT THEME** directory `style.css`it works..

How can I get it work when I put CSS on my **child theme responsive.css**

test site is [HERE](http://asiamediaglobal.net/riffaz/athavan-eng/)

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618751/ipad-portrait-css-styling-isnt-working